# same server, get url: vbscript msxml3.dll 80004005 unspecified error, or msxml6.dll error '80072ee6' System error: -2147012890

Tags: vbscript, iis-6, serverxmlhttp

What's the correct way to get the output of an asp page located on the same server?

```
<%

GetUrl "/route/to/abc/123/"

Function GetUrl(url)
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", URL, false
    objXMLHTTP.send()
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        Response.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseText
    End if
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function

%>
```

results in this pesky error.

```
msxml3.dll error '80004005'
Unspecified error
/test.asp, line 7
```

switching up to a newer serverxmlhttp

```
set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
```

reveals a different, more meaningful error:

```
msxml6.dll error '80072ee6'
System error: -2147012890.
/test.asp, line 8
```

which google happily found an reason to, which says "Don't use serverXmlHttp to connect to the same server. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316451) What do you use? The article didn't offer much.

Anyway cool, there's a proper reason for my error. But what DO you use to connect to the same server, under classic asp, to capture the output of pages? This article (https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/aa23d158-000a-4ba2-8fe8-99895854d7f0.mspx?mfr=true) mentions if I'm doing isolation mode, then the process runs seperate to the web server process and there I can't use SSI, I can't figure out how to enable it in the first place anyway. It sounds nasty anyway. SSI is **critical** in my app, so I can't consider it.

What am I left with (besides the obvious: ditch ASP)? spawn a wscript.shell command prompt and pull it from there, echoing back to stdout? bounce off another reflector server? Grr

Comment: Since you have exactly 30 days until support for Windows Server 2003 (and IIS 6) ends, I'd say your primary concern right now should be migrating to IIS 7+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot request web page from web site which are running under *the same Application pool*.

> A finite number of worker threads (in the Inetinfo.exe or Dllhost.exe
>   process) is available to execute ASP pages. If all of the ASP worker
>   threads send HTTP requests back to the same Inetinfo.exe or
>   Dllhost.exe process on the server from which the requests are sent,
>   the Inetinfo.exe or Dllhost.exe process may deadlock or stop
>   responding (hang), because the pool of worker threads to process the
>   incoming requests will be exhausted. This is by design.
>
> If a single recursive request causes IIS to deadlock, the typical
>   cause is that ASP script debugging is enabled.

Solution: create new folder, put your script inside this folder. After that in IIS create new Application pool and also create new application for this folder.

How to create new application for some folder:
[image]

Sample when folder assigned to new application pool:
[image]

NOTE: Do not try 3rd part DLL's for download web page from the same application pool. Result will be the same. Tested with some free http component.

Comment: Putting the script into a new folder requires some engineering work in my routes and views, but hey it's it better than scraping the output of wget off a command shell... cheers :) (the ms documentation was doing my head in, alongside all the other "fixes" google suggested)